# Unable to add modal popup window in aspx

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

This is my current code which gives you the output as displayed below

```
<div class="MarketPlaceWidgetHead">Marketplace</div>
<div id="divSupplier" runat="server"> //The details are got from the .cs file
</div>
```

[image: I get this]

I want to make it such that the items present inside the divSupplier
        gets displayed in a popup when a button is pressed such as the one given below.

[image: Type that i want]

Ive tried using modalpopup window,

(http://pastebin.com/6sM384we followed this example and got this http://pastebin.com/SrH2YTYZ) it shows me errors such as

unrecognized tag prefix or device filter ajaxcontroltoolkit.

or can someone guide me on using fancybox ?

Comment: Why dont you use JQuery.Dialog? or Fancybox is also good and easy to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [Fancybox][1].

You should use fancybox inline type.
Here is how to use.

Add div tag set runat server and display none.

```
<div runat="server" id="divPopup" style="display:none">
</div>
```

You can access divPopup from code behind.
Now set the content of the popup from the code behind.

```
divPopup.InnerHtml="items.... (with html)";
```

And add a link for show popup.

```
<a class="fancybox" id="inline" href="#divPopup">Show Popup</a>
```

NOT: You have to import scripts for fancybox.fancybox includes that files at /lib/ folder.

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
```

Comment: <div id="divSupplier" runat="server" style="display:none"></div>                         <a class="fancybox" href="#inline">Get Items</a>

thats my code in the aspx and i'm getting the values from the .cs file, 
    divSupplier.InnerHtml = GameSupplier.GetGameSupplier(Game);
i still don't get the popup but the url appends the value file.aspx **#inline**

Comment: you have to add a script for define fancybox popups <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.fancybox').fancybox();
 
 </script>

Comment: u might be missing some requirement for fancybox.check it from http://fancybox.net/howto/

Answer (score 1):

you can use [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).easy to use.

Comment: the content that needs to be inside the pop are in the div tag, how'd i insert the div tag in the anchor tag ?

Comment: use fancybox with inline type.
u have to add a div tag and set the display none.

<div id="inline" style="display:none">
items....>
</div>

<a class="fancybox" href="#inline">item</a>

this div will be your popup div.

Comment: i got the a tag to work but when i click the anchor tag it stays in the same page the popup doesn't appear and yes i have added the required header files.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting errors in those examples you are trying to implement because you have not imported the Ajax tool kit reference.Clearly Visual Studio is moaning loudly about this 'unrecognized tag prefix or device filter ajaxcontroltoolkit.'

Add a reference to the Ajax Toolkit in your project.Download it [here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/).
Unzip and extract the AjaxControlToolKit.dll file and reference it to your project.
Register it on the asxc control like this.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

And use it like this

```
    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" TargetControlId="btnShowmodal"    PopupControlID="pnlmodal" 
                         BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" OkControlID="okBtn" DropShadow="true">

                         </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Hope this will help.
Download working demo [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m1t1lgx494qgxz3/WebSite20.zip) and open Default2.aspx.